# Last_Insert_ID and OK PACKET

Tags: mysql, generics, response, packet

In MySQL when inserting to a table with an `AUTO INCREMENT` column the [manual suggests](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html) that a user should roughly follow this pattern

```
INSERT INTO tbl (auto,text) VALUES(NULL,'text');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The question I have is in the [OK PACKET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/packet-OK_Packet.html) it contains a field called `last_insert_id`. Is this value the same as using `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`?

The manual itself contains no information on this field, the ORM I'm using exposes this field. I'm wondering if I can us it, instead of making another network round trip.

Comment: use it until it doesn't work :p

Comment: I'm going to test it in a few hours, just I was hoping to know before I wrote my storage procedure code so I don't have to re-write it :(

Comment: Crack out the champagne I say !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be yes.

The `last_insert_id` field in the [`OK PACKET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/packet-OK_Packet.html) is indeed redundant to making a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` query.

I ran a handful of tests to do about 30-40 inserts scattered between 3 columns of data and in every occasion the `last_insert_id` field was indeed equal to the value I received from `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`